# QTP: JavaScript synchronization

Tags: javascript, synchronization, qtp

There is a frame which content is loaded by a javascript.

```
<iframe ... onload="pageLoaded();">
```

A QTP test needs to wait until it finishes loading. The frame content can differ basing on user settings, so checking for existense of an element in the frame is not an option.

Is there a way to wait in QTP until all content is loaded without trying to check for existence of some element?

Comment: What is the next step in the test? Even if the content can differ based on user settings you have to interact with a specific element, can't you synchronize on that?

Comment: @Motti. This is a frame where a user spends most of the time. There are only navigation panels outside of this frame. So I wanted to have a generic function to sync with a frame. Meanwhile, I've created a function that waits and checks for presence of any child table inside (as you suggest). It's not an elegant solution. If web templates change, e.g. to use divs instead of tables, I'll need to change all tests. It would be strange, if QTP cannot do JavaScript synchronization. I used Watir for the same tests and didn't have any such problems at all.

Comment: >>If web templates change, e.g. to use divs instead of tables, I'll need to change all tests. << You could isolate that code in a function and put that in a function library. If the function interface is generic enough, chances are good you have to modify the library code only if the web template changes.

Comment: @TheBlastOne That's what I did in the end. Thank you. If you made it as an answer, I would mark it as accepted.

Comment: @katmooon: Doh! But: Whenever I see the comments thread contains a suggestion which I can convert to a useful solution by adding one particular aspect, I just do a comment, and do not create an answer repeating the thread's ideas (plus my addendums) because it might spoil the other people that initiated the comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways:

The most simple one, use the hidden sync method on the page object:

```
oPage.sync    ' Where oPage is your page object
```

If this don't work, you can get the wait property of your browser object:

```
if oBrowser.WaitProperty("state", micRegExpMatch("4|complete"), 60 * 1000) then
    msgbox "Browser is ready!"
else
    msgbox "Even after 1 minute, the browser is not ready :("
end if
```

Alternatively you can get the statusbar, the text and see if there is the text "Waiting" in it (IE only)

```
Set oStatusBar = Browser("micclass:=Browser").WinStatusBar("nativeclass:=msctls_statusbar32")
Do : Loop Until instr(oStatusBar.GetROProperty("text"), "Waiting") = 0
```

Or the progressbar:

```
Set oProgressBar = Browser("micclass:=Browser").WinObject("nativeclass:=msctls_progress32")
Do : Loop Until oProgressBar.getROproperty("visible")
```

(Code is simplified. As you know QTP, you have to check on the existence of the objects and properties before accessing them.)